# How to save user data in C# Winstore Metro app permanently?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have some user data in my Winstore C# app. I just learnt that local store and app data are being erased after new version of the app is installed (or user reinstalled the app).

How to permanently store the data? Can it be done transparently for the user?

What about enterprise class of apps - how do you guys access more robust data like databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like Skydrive or Dropbox to store the files.

EDIT*

There is no database access support in WinRT. While you can use something like SQLite to store data locally - it would be used mostly for caching and it would be expected that you persist the data somewhere in the cloud, so you should still upload the data you want stored somewhere outside of your machine.

If you want to store files on your machine that don't get deleted with your app - you can save them somewhere in the documents/pictures/music/videos libraries, depending on where they fit best.

Comment: I need to store it under the app login. not individual user login. can it be done? do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used these myself, but there should be plenty of examples out there since these are common scenarios. What do you mean by app login? Would you like all users of your app to store their files in the same location? I doubt there is a free solution that could support that.

Comment: yes. to store all users in one place. I need to make the solution transparent for the users - no signing in no accepting TCs etc... you have to use file picker each time you read/write from documents libraries. right? so each time you will have to ask user to do so...correct?

Comment: In my experience using file picker every time was not necessary with a pitcures library, though there might be some guideline recommending it.

Comment: apparently the answer is - RTFM :) you were right in a sense. you can declare a capability and associate a specific file type to your app and use documents library.. somehow I overlooked it when I was reading about file access. thanks for tipping me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Removing all local data when an app is uninstalled is the expected pattern for Windows Store apps.

If you want to store data permanently, my recommendation is that you consider building a back-end data store and services to access them. Then you control the server-side data, and can associate the data with the users when they install your app (note that if you plan to store data and not delete it when the user uninstalls the app, you should probably call that out in your app's privacy policy).

There are several good options in terms of building back-end services, and I explore several of them in a blog series I'm currently working on:

http://bitly.com/bundles/devhammer/2

The series covers building a back-end game leaderboard service which stores data in a SQL Database on Windows Azure (though the concepts are applicable to services you host yourself as well), using one of 3 stacks:

1. WCF Data Services
2. ASP.NET Web API
3. Windows Azure Mobile Services

Any of those three stacks will allow you to create a robust back-end for your apps, and can be leveraged across platforms.

With respect to transparency, you can definitely make the above services functionally transparent to the user, but as noted above, it's a good idea to also be transparent about the fact that you plan to continue to store data after the app is uninstalled, and perhaps even give the user options for deleting their data. Pete Brown recently posted a good overview of traits of a good Windows Store app privacy policy, and addresses this a bit in the post:

http://10rem.net/blog/2013/01/21/traits-of-a-good-windows-store-app-privacy-policy

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: thanks for promoting your webservice. however it is not what I was asking for.

Comment: You asked how to store data in a Windows Store app that will not be deleted automatically when the app is uninstalled. I offered you information on several solutions to that problem. Sorry if the solution isn't what you were after, but I'm glad to see you got an answer that was more in line with what you were looking for.

Comment: > If you want to store data permanently, my recommendation is that you consider building a back-end data store and services to access them - please... mate.. I am not new on the market. what you have said is - if you want fresh bread - my recommendation is to build a bakery... oh coincidentally - I am selling excellent out of the box automated bakery .. right... I can write backend server in few hours and put it in production in matter of minutes... just - why to bother?